# Insert using std::transform into destination, from a specific destination offset

Tags: c++, stl, std

I need to insert in a destination vector, but not from the begging of the vector, but using an offset.
This is my current code, but destination vector is filled from the first element. I want to make use of the offset variable, to insert from a specific position.

Any sugestions ? Thanks

To be clear: I want to use the offset on the destination vector, not on the source.

```
  #include <cstdlib>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <map>
  #include <vector>
  #include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
  #include <algorithm>
  #include<iterator>

  using namespace std;

  std::string intToStr(int i){

  return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i);
  }

  struct Movie
  {
  Movie()
      : id(0), title("title") { }

  Movie(int id, const std::string &title)
      : id(id), title(title) { }


  int id;            //!< item index
  std::string title; //!< item title
  };

  struct GetTitle { std::string operator()(const Movie& cat) const { return cat.title; } };

  int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  int offset = 5;

  std::vector<Movie> p_playlist;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
      p_playlist.push_back(Movie(i, std::string("Name ") + intToStr(i)));


  std::vector<string> mEntries;
  std::transform(p_playlist.begin(), p_playlist.end(),   std::back_inserter(mEntries) , GetTitle());


  for(int i=0; i < mEntries.size(); i++)
    cout << mEntries[i] << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the destination vector has no elements, the `back_inserter` of course inserts from the first element. It just calls `push_back`, nothing magic. So you will have to insert the first N elements before you `back_insert` the rest:

```
std::vector<string> mEntries;
insertFirstNElems(mEntries);
std::transform(p_playlist.begin(), p_playlist.end(),   std::back_inserter(mEntries) ,    GetTitle());

//... for example:
void insertFirstNElems(std::vector<string>& vec) {
  vec.resize(42, "meow");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the other vector elements in first.  If necessary, use `resize(n)` to default-construct `n` initial elements before doing your back insertions.